# Which of the following sentences are correct when using the verb "cheer", and why? Thank you!

Tags: verbs

1. Looking forward to cheering on, you and your team.
2. Looking forward to cheering on you and your team.
3. Looking forward to cheer on, you and your team.
4. Looking forward to cheer on you and your team.
5. Looking forward to cheering for you and your team.
6. Looking forward to cheer for you and your team.

Comment: Those aren't complete sentences. But these are correct: *Looking forward to cheering on you and your team.* *Looking forward to cheering for you and your team.*

Comment: It's a fixed phrase: look forward to ing. The 'to' is a preposition so it needs a noun, pronoun, or gerund, i.e., equivalents to nouns

Comment: _Cheer on_ is a phrasal verb, and in this case the _on_ adds nothing and can profitably be ignored until the end: _Looking forward to cheering you and your team on._